# how to assign values to an array using .subscribe in angular?

Tags: angular

I am using a HttpClient calling.I am trying to assign values to posts[] which i hav defined as type any.

I am getting error as follows:

> The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
>     Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

My code for posts.component.html

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: any[];

  constructor(http:HttpClient) { 

    http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(response =>{
      this.posts=response;})
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: Does your response contains `object` ?

Comment: I am getting values from URL http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts.

Comment: Can you print here the response you get in the subscribe?

Comment: Just try to give a type to your response like .....subscribe((response: any[]) => { ....

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the type of the response:

```
http.get<any[]>('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(response => {
  this.posts = response;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should type your `httpClient.get` method call, like this:

```
http.get<any[]>('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(response => {
   this.posts = response;
})
```

Best practice is also to create an `interface` for your model, for example:

```
export interface Post {
  id: number,
  title: string,
  ...
}
```

So your code could be :

```
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {
  posts: Post[];

  constructor(http: HttpClient) { 

    http.get<Post[]>('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(response => {
      this.posts = response;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```